# How to remove obj form three.js scene

Tags: html, three.js

I am building a small website with three.js (I am a absolute beginner). My website is working fine but I want to remove a obj from the scene. How can I do this?

What I want is that when I click a button, the OBJ disappears. How can I do this?

My code:

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.149.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.149.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import { OBJLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
    import { GUI } from 'three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    
    const loader = new OBJLoader();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    camera.position.z = 20;
    camera.position.y = 20;

    const light = new THREE.SpotLight()
    light.position.set(10, 5, 5)
    scene.add(light)

    function loadtavel(){
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'assets/objtest.obj',
            // called when resource is loaded
            function ( object ) {

                scene.add( object );
                // object.translateZ( 10 );
            },
            // called when loading is in progresses
            function ( xhr ) {

                console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

            },
            // called when loading has errors
            function ( error ) {

                console.log( 'An error happened' );

            }
        );
    }

    
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'assets/untitled.obj',
        // called when resource is loaded
        function ( object ) {

            scene.add( object );
            object.translateY( 10 );
        },
        // called when loading is in progresses
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {

            console.log( 'An error happened' );

        }
    );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
    
    function removeLoad(){

    }

    // renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true
    // renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
    renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
    

    // texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    var obj = {
        add: function() {
            loadtavel();
        }
    };
    var obj2 = {
        add: function() {
            removeLoad()
        }
    };

    

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        // cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        // cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };

    animate();
    const gui = new GUI()
    const cubeFolder = gui.addFolder('Cube')
    cubeFolder.add(obj, 'add').name('Load!');
    cubeFolder.add(obj2, 'add').name('Unload!');
    cubeFolder.open()
</script>
</html>
```

I already searched for a solution but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the OBJ disappear, you could just change its visibility:

```
obj.visibility = false;
```

If you want to remove it from the scene, just do so with:

```
scene.remove(obj);
```

Comment: Oke thank you, but how can I make from my loaded obj a object which I can use?

Comment: You can find that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971867/2608515